# In WCF can you re-use endpoint behaviors, service behaviors and bindings?

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration-files, wcf-binding, wcf-behaviour

In WCF can you re-use endpoint behaviors, service behaviors and bindings?
Or must each service / endpoint have distinct ones even if they are the same except for their ID.

Comment: You're not "re-using" them as such because in your config they're not an object, they're simply a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse them - just specify the appropriate one(s) (via the name you gave them in their section) for the endpoints in question.

For example, assume you have a service behavior named "MyServiceBehavior", a wsHttpBinding named "MyWsHttpBinding" and an endpoint behavior named "MyEndpointBehavior".

For the service behavior, you'd use the `behaviorConfiguration` attribute (`behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"`) in the `<service>` element.

For the binding and endpoint behavior, you'd use the `bindingConfiguration` attribute (`bindingConfiguration="MyWsHttpBinding"`) and the `behaviorConfiguration` attribute (`behaviorConfiguration="MyEndpointBehavior"`) of the `<endpoint>` element.